# Case condition with lag function in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, case

This is my data,

act.  balance  start_date.  end_date
123.  -85.     2019-11-10.  2019-11-12
123.  -185.    2019-11-13   2019-11-13
123.  -79.     2023-03-19.  2023-04-12
123  -180.     2023-04-13.  2023-05-31
'''

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| act | balance | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | -85 | 2019-11-10 | 2019-11-12 |
| 123 | -185 | 2019-11-13 | 2019-11-13 |
| 123 | -79 | 2023-03-19 | 2023-04-12 |
| 123 | -180 | 2023-04-13 | 2023-05-31 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

I want number of days between start and end date, row 1 and 2 are in continuity so I want new start and end date should give following result.

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| act | balance | start_date | end_date | new_start_date | new_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | -85 | 2019-11-10 | 2019-11-12 | 2019-11-10 | 2019-11-13 |
| 123 | -185 | 2019-11-13 | 2019-11-13 | 2019-11-10 | 2019-11-13 |
| 123 | -79 | 2023-03-19 | 2023-04-12 | 2023-03-19 | 2023-05-31 |
| 123 | -180 | 2023-04-13 | 2023-05-31 | 2023-03-19 | 2023-05-31 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

I was trying to think a logic if previous end date and start date has difference as 1 or 2 then it should create a partition based on condition then return min start date and max end date but I don't know how to create that partition.
I will use datediff() to calculate the days, but I want my output to give results like this.

Comment: _[how to create that partition](https://dbfiddle.uk/AqHFrLny)_